# Intellij IDEA Structural Replace PHP

Tags: php, templates, intellij-idea, structural-search

I want to replace an expression everywhere in my project. So I use the Structural Replace...
But I got an error when I specify the Replacement Pattern :

```
Unsupported Replacement Pattern : Partial and expression patterns are not supported
```

Here is my Search Template :

```
$_COOKIE[$Index$]
```

Here is my Replacement Template :

```
my_function($_COOKIE[$Index$])
```

Thank you for your help ;)

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-35509

Comment: Upgrading the IDE or using PHPStorm didn't helped me... but thank you for your help ;) (if you have an other solution I still want it for a next time ;) )

Comment: @ValentinLecompte did you solve it?